# LESS.js isn't working, I'm aware of the chrome bug... using Firefox

Tags: less

Firefox isn't reading any of the styling. Not even the width or height. Am I missing some part of the setup?

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Learning Less</title>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.18.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <a href="#">Hello World</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Stylesheet style.less

```
@primary-color: red;

#container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: @primary-color;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax all looks correct - what happens if you view the request in firebug?  Do you see a 404 for style.less?  Some web servers need a little bit of help to serve up .less files - which web server are you using?  Are you running the HTML file locally with file://?

Comment: It's getting the style.less file under XHR? You'd think it'd be under CSS or JS. No 404 though. I'm on my work server, I don't know much about it.

Comment: I got it to work. I just had to download the library and call it instead of using the Google repository.

Comment: Good. You can post your own answer and accept it.